# How to pass array of arguments to azure vm powershell extension from ansible playbook?

Tags: azure, powershell, ansible

I am trying to pass array arguments of type "string" from ansible playbook to powershell script which needs to be run as vm extension against a VM running in azure cloud.Below is the ansible playbook code

```
  - name: Create VM extension
    azure_rm_virtualmachine_extension:
       name: "Extension"
       location: "{{ var_location  }}"
       resource_group: "{{ var_ResourceGroup }}"
       virtual_machine_name: "{{ var_vmname }}"
       publisher: Microsoft.Compute
       state: present
       virtual_machine_extension_type: CustomScriptExtension
       type_handler_version: "1.9"
       auto_upgrade_minor_version: true
       settings: '{"fileUris": ["{{ var_powershellscriptUrl }}"]}'
       protected_settings: '{"commandToExecute": "[powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File {{PowershellUserScriptFileName }} -arg1 {{ Arrayofstring1 }} -arg2 {{ Arrayofstring2 }} -arg3 {{ Arrayofstring3 }} ]"}'
    ignore_errors: true
```

Output of below code

```
- debug:
   msg: {{ Arrayofstring1 }} 

   is    \"VM1\", \"VM2\", \"VM3\"
```

Error which am getting while executing playbook is

> "msg": "argument protected_settings is of type type 'str' and we were
>   unable to convert to dict: unable to evaluate string as dictionary"}

Question is how should i pass array of these parameters to powershell code from ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.6/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/azure/azure_rm_virtualmachineextension.py#L180-L182) it seems that no matter what the documentation shows, they actually want a `dict` to appear in that parameter, so try providing that data structure and see if things improve

```
- name: Create VM extension
  azure_rm_virtualmachineextension:
    protected_settings:
      commandToExecute: "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File {{PowershellUserScriptFileName }} -arg1 {{ Arrayofstring1 }} -arg2 {{ Arrayofstring2 }} -arg3 {{ Arrayofstring3 }}"
```

Comment: Hi daniel, could you please remove '[ ' and ']' from your answer....the code commandToExecute: "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File somefile.ps1" works fine for me and not with '[' and ']'...Thanks for helping out anyway

Comment: I used them because you used them; I don't have an azure account to actually test out that code before posting it